# How to input the value of a hidden field into a textbox with Test Cafe Studio?

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I am attempting to input the value of a hidden field into a textbox in Testcafe, ideally in some sort of manner that simulates typing.  Is there a way to do that?  Every time I try to do it via javascript it just throws a javascript error.

Essentially I am testing a pretty standard web app - I fill out a form, go page to page, and then must type in a value that is kept in a hidden html input field on the page.  I honestly have no idea where to start  - every time I've tried to do this with javascript via the "Run Test Cafe Script" it has thrown a javascript error - I really don't know where to start if javascript can't be used.

Comment: Could you please update your question with a simple project and your test code?

Comment: I expanded the question a bit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TestCafe cannot type text in a zero-size input element. I suggest you try the Run TestCafe Script action with ClientFunction that puts a value to the input element directly:

```
const setValue = ClientFunction(() => {
    document.querySelector('input[type="hidden"]').value = 'John Smith';
});

await setValue();
```

Comment: That's it!  Thank you.